# What do we call a place, which is a plane land just beneath a mountain range?

Tags: geography

I want to describe about a village. It is not a mountain village. It is located just at the border from where hills started to rise.

Comment: Do you mean a "plain land"? If so the answer is "a plain" - i.e. flat ground at the foot of hills or mountains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary.com defines [***piedmont***](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/piedmont) as

> An area of land, glacier, or other feature formed or lying at the foot of a mountain or mountain range.
>
> *adjective
>
>   (prenominal)* (of glaciers, plains, etc) formed or situated at the foot of a mountain or mountain range

And is from *pied* (foot)  *monte* (hill),  thus ***foothills***  also works.

Comment: In my experience, the definition given by Wikipedia is more accurate here: “gradual increases in elevation at the base of a mountain range, higher hill range or an upland area”. That is, foothills to me are not _plain_, but have some elevation. Not all mountains have foothills – some rise very sharply and go straight from plain to mountain. (It’s not quite clear from the question whether the beginning elevation of the foothills or the flatness of the plain is what the asker is looking for or not.)

Comment: I don’t disagree.  I think foothills and piedmont both have some element of elevation prior to the steep ascent of the mountain range itself. But some are quite rolling and smooth and compared to the mountains can be considered more flat than mountain.  Do a google image search for piedmont and see the kinds of things that show up.

Comment: @ JIm and  Janus Bahs Jacquet, thanks much for your clarification and patience. It helped me to think of texts describing the scenario. To be more specific, I shall say that the village has got a landscape, where it is plain. And, surrounded by forests on threes sides at the foothills of a mountain range.

Comment: Unless OP clarifies that they don't require a term for **flat** terrain, I'll have to downvote here later.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth- In this case, I think the important part to capture is "at the border from where the hills start to rise"  The only word I know of that gets at that transition area is piedmont. Other than that you're stuck with "base of the mountains" or "edge of the plains"  [Here's a picture of Italy's Piedmont area](https://images.app.goo.gl/tNsuGL3BBrSiMv8Q8): While there is some elevation and gentle rolling of the terrain it's pretty plain-like when compared to the mountains.